# Laravel 5.4: attach custom service provider to a controller

Tags: laravel-5.4, service-provider

I created a service provider named AdminServiceProvider

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Modules\Orders\Models\Orders;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
class AdminServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {

        public function boot()
        {
            $comments = Orders::get_new_comments();
            View::share('comments', $comments);
        }
        public function register()
        {

        }
    }
```

Registered the provider

```
App\Providers\AdminServiceProvider::class,
```

Now I try to attach it to the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\AdminServiceProvider;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public $lang;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('admin/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Now I get this error message

```
Undefined variable: comments
```

This is the first time I try to use a custom service provider and don't know exactly how it works I'm sure there's something missing Hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE]

removed use App\Providers\AdminServiceProvider; from the controller

php artisan clear-compiled solved the problem but I want to attach it to some controllers not all controllers as the $comments are sent to all contollers in my app. So how to attach the service provider to specific controllers not all of them?

Comment: php artisan clear-compiled solved the problem but I want to attach it to some controllers not all controllers

Comment: check the modified answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the undefined variable run: `php artisan clear-compiled` will solve it

**If you want to share a variable in some of your views** you can create a middleware and assign it to the views you want to share the data with:

- First create a middleware: `php artisan make:middleware someName`
- Then in the handle function you add your view sharing logic:

> ```
>  $comments = Orders::get_new_comments(); 
>  view()->share('comments',$comments);
>  return $next($request);
> ```

- Then register your middleware under the `$routeMiddleware` array and
  give it an alias.

Then attach it to your routes like:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=> 'yourMiddlewwareName'], function(){
  //your routes
});
```

Comment: That what I was doing but was looking for a simple solution to add the code one time instead of repeating it in every admin controller.

Comment: To respond to your comment, you can have all admin controllers extend a base admin controller, and add the middleware in the base admin controller constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all your admin views in one directory (`views\admin` for example) you can use view composer in `AdminServiceProvider`:

```
public function boot()
{
        view()->composer('admin.*', function($view){
             $view->with('comments', Orders::get_new_comments());
        });

}
```

It will attach `comments` variable to each view in your `views\admin` directory.

You can also attach a variable to some specific views or folders like this:

```
view()->composer(['admin.posts.*', 'admin.pages.index'], function($view){
      $view->with('comments', Orders::get_new_comments());
 });
```